# django - superuser password hash in dumpdata json file

Tags: django, sentry

Hi can someone tell me what hash is used by django store superuser data ?
I'm asking because I'd like to pre-generate password hash, stick it into prepared json fixture and load the user automatically via script. I just need to know how to prepare particular password hash.
Thanks

Comment: Install django, generate the superuser, then use python manage --dumpdata to generate the fixture. Would that not work for you?

Comment: if I want to automate the install the NO. I dont want to install MANUALLY and then set up superuser. I want to install automatically from scratch.

Comment: Sorry I think you misunderstood me. I mean do it manually, once, the first time, and use the output of dumpdata for your automation. It'll save more brain cycles then trying to execute the django `set_password` function on your proposed password. Be aware that the SECRET_KEY setting is used in the generation of the hash that gets stored in the DB, so make sure it's consistent in your automation.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Josh Smeaton. I did what you advised - generated the password manually first time, then dumped the auth DB into json:

```
sentry --config=/etc/sentry.conf.py dumpdata --indent=2 auth > ~/auth_data.json
```

Created a new fixture out of the dumped json file:

```
[
 {
    "pk": 1,
    "model": "auth.user",
    "fields": {
      "username": "somuser",
      "first_name": "Johnny",
      "last_name": "Bravo",
      "is_active": true,
      "is_superuser": true,
      "is_staff": true,
      "last_login": "2012-06-24 01:13:08",
      "groups": [],
      "user_permissions": [],
      "password": "<password_hash>",
      "email": "some@someother.com",
      "date_joined": "2012-06-24 01:10:30"
    }
  }
]
```

And loaded it automatically without any interaction as follows:

```
sentry --config=/etc/sentry.conf.py loaddata ~/superuser.json
```

Answer (score 0):

By default user passwords are hashed using [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2). You can easily change this.

The hash is stored in the format `algorithm$hash`.

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/

Comment: By default in version 1.4 - earlier was sha1.

Answer (score 0):

The hash used depends on the version of Django you're using. From the Django docs:

> Django 1.4 introduces a new flexible password storage system and uses PBKDF2 by default. Previous versions of Django used SHA1, and other algorithms couldn't be chosen.

For more information, check out the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#how-django-stores-passwords).

Comment: how would I go about generating the password on the commandline. Let's say I want to set the password to "password" then "hash it" via whatever authentication django use it and get the output. There must be a way to do this as the output can be put into json fixture and loaded automatically - I'm sure some automatic tests must be doing this somehow.

Comment: Check out the function PBKDF2PasswordHasher at https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py for details on the specific implementation of the password hashing.